# clrzmq c# examples not work

Tags: c#, binding, zeromq

I have trouble with official zeromq binding for c#:
https://github.com/zeromq/clrzmq

Here is an example of subscriber: https://github.com/imatix/zguide/blob/master/examples/C%23/psenvsub.cs

I've done all steps in MS Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate, but this example doesn't work.

First, I have found no namespace ZMQ, but ZeroMQ have.
Second, there is wrong syntax:

```
subscriber.Subscribe("B", Encoding.Unicode);
```

> Error 1   No overload for method 'Subscribe' takes 2
>   arguments D:\LANG\c#\zmqtest\quotesclient\quotesclient.cs 23  21  quotesclient

Definition is like here:

```
public virtual void Subscribe(byte[] prefix);
```

Please, tell me, what is going on with this binding?
And how to work with zeromq in c# ?

Answer (score 2):

Did you get clrzmq through nuget? Did you check the version you got in package.config ? Was caught by the fact that nuget provides version 2 ("stable") of clrzmq if you don't pick the "Include prerelease" option in the package manager and specifically ask for version 3 ("beta"). APIs have changed between the two versions.

Comment: David! You'd opened my eyes! Thank's, I'v got the stable version 2 and all samples begin to work.
Could you tell me, where can I see valid subscriber example for version 3 ?

Comment: When you download the clrzmq sources, you have several examples. See, for example, in \src\ZeroMQ.Perf.ThrLocal subdirectory.